# Does the Mac mini with M1 support the LG 5k display?

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt-display, apple-silicon

I have the 1st gen LG ultrafine display. Will it work with the 2020 Mac mini M1-based machine?

Update: The LG 5k 1st gen is quite prickly. It doesn't work with an AMD eGPU which does work with the 2nd gen LG. It seems to have some non-standard DisplayPort over thunderbolt implementation. This egpu.io article has details: https://egpu.io/forums/gpu-monitor-peripherals/lg-ultrafine-5k-now-usb-c-powered/

Comment: The specs of both the monitor and the M1 are available on the respective website. Assuming you've looked at these already, what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2):

So far, it does not. Just connected my new M1 to my LG Ultrafine 5k and it blanks out randomly despite using the same connection that works fine with my 2018 Macbook Pro and despite the M1 Mini driving a 4k VewSonic (HDMI) without any issues (which looks quite nice, but would prefer to be able to use the 5K and its built in camera.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mini M1 and an LG 4K Ultrafine.  I first connected the display with an OWC Thunderbolt cable, and had problems waking the display.  I bought an Apple Thunderbolt Cable (0.8 m) and that fixed all problems. So any problems may not be with the devices on each end !